# Ftp возможности в андроиде, какие они?

Tags: ftp, android, java

Я могу только скачивать и закачивать файлы? Можно их просматривать, допустим видео? 
Я хочу по ftp найти допустим видео, выбрать посмотреть, после просмотра закрыть без сохранения на диске? Это как папка tmp в линуксе.

Comment: вы же понимаете что в любом случае его нужно скачать?
другой вопрос в том позволяет ли формат видео а точнее видео кодек декодировать видео пока ещё не весь файл загрузился..

Comment: Конечно понимаю, что видео будет скачано.